# protonbridge with claws-mail

Tags: email, mail-user-agent

Has anyone used claws-mail with proton email, via protonbridge, or otherwise? claws-mail requires a fairly manual setup, and protonbridge is pretty sparse with the information it provides.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `claws-mail` but I use Proton Mail Bridge with `evolution`, which works perfect. I assume the process is pretty much the same:

1. Add new account.
2. Enter credentials provided by Proton Mail Bridge (username + pw).
3. Set `localhost` (127.0.0.1) as IMAP and SMTP.
4. Set 1143 as port and STARTTLS for IMAP; 1025 as port and STARTTLS for SMTP.
5. When you get prompted for the certificate, confirm that you want to add the security exception (permanently).
6. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Claws Mail is fairly opinionated about a few things that are smoothed over in other email clients. It keeps your accounts separate, including the "Queued Messages"/"Outbox."

Proton Mail does not have a place for these besides the "Sent" messages. In order to send mail, you will need to create a folder for Claws Mail to use as a temporary "outbox." Don't worry, Claws fully manages this and does not expect Proton Mail to do anything with this folder.

To use Proton Mail Bridge with Claws Mail, go to Configuration -> Create New Account

- Basic Tab

  - Mail address: *[Your Proton email address to use]*
  - Protocol: IMAP
  - Server for receiving: 127.0.0.1
  - SMTP server (send): 127.0.0.1
  - User ID: *[Your "Username" indicated in Proton Mail Bridge]*
  - Password: *[Your Password generated by the Proton Mail Bridge app]*
- Receive Tab

  - *UNCHECK* "Show subscribed folders only"
  - Check 'Get Mail' checks for new messages on this account
- Send Tab

  - Check "SMTP Authentication (SMTP AUTH)"
  - Authentication method: Automatic
- TLS Tab

  - IMAP: "Use StartTTLS command to start encrypted session"
  - Send (SMTP): "Use StartTTLS command to start encrypted session"
- Advanced Tab

  - SMTP port: 1025 *[As indicated in Proton Mail Bridge]*
  - IMAP port: 1143 *[As indicated in Proton Mail Bridge]*
  - **Put Queued Messages In: [Create a folder for Outgoing mail]**
- Press "OK"

When prompted about the SSL certificate, accept it.